# Indecomposable representations of a wreath product

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, we know the irreducible representations of $G ≀ S_n$ (over $\mathbb Q$) are classified by partitions of $n$ 'decorated' by an irrep of $G$.

I'm wondering to what extent the same classification holds if $G$ is infinite: what are the indecomposable representations of $G ≀ S_n$ over $\mathbb Q$? Is there ever any kind of similar classification, or is it totally hopeless?

I'm willing to impose as many conditions on $G$ as necessary: for example, what if $G = \mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: If you stick to irreducible representations of finite dimension, rather than indecomposable, quite a lot of Clifford Theory would seem to go through, since the base group of the wreath product has finite index. So irreducible representations of the wreath product are induced from irreducible representations of direct products of smaller such wreath products corresponding to Young subgroups.